# Where is the right place to put _changed? methods in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a user model that checks to see if a value has changed before_save (by running User.zipcode_changed?).  The idea is that this will queue up a delayed job if it has.

Problem is, when I migrate the app from scratch I get an error:

```
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `postcode_changed?' for #<User:0x105db6158>
```

Therefore, where should I be putting these?  Is the model the wrong place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you checkout a new project from scratch, you shouldn't use migrations to build the database.
You should use `rake db:schema:load` instead.

Let me show you why.

Let's assume you create a new `Post` model with a post table on migration 10.
On migration 11, you execute some special elaborations on the `Post` model.
After a while, you decide to drop the `Post` model and the post table because no longer required.

Six month later, you checkout the project from scratch. If you try to run `rake db:migrate` the migration 11 will fail complaining about missing model. It's true, the model has been removed many month before and it's no longer available.

Instead, if you run `rake db:schema:load` you'll initialize the database with the right schema version.

Talking about migrations, if you just created the postcode method and you are trying to use the _changed? magic method in the same migration, you need to reload the schema before.

```
class MigrationFile < ...
  self.up
    add_column :user, :postcode, :string

    User.all.each { |user| puts user.postcode_changed? }  # will fail 

    User.reset_column_information
    User.all.each { |user| puts user.postcode_changed? }  # now it works
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: I should probably point out that this code is in the model, not the controller, but I see your point.

Comment: I never talked about the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You say both zipcode_changed? and postcode_changed? in your question. What's the actual column name in your database - zipcode or postcode? ActiveRecord will only create the _changed? convenience method for the actual column name.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is reasonable model code, but not so good in a migration.

Using model code in your migrations is problematic because of problems like this. I recommend sticking with SQL-oriented code.